# Import content from filenames defined in an array

Tags: d, ctfe

I can concatenate files read by `import` during compile time like this:

```
enum string a = import("a.txt");
enum string b = import("b.txt");
enum string result = a ~ b;
```

How can I get the concatenated `result` if I have the filenames in an array?

```
enum files = ["a.txt", "b.txt"];
string result;
foreach (f; files) {
  result ~= import(f);
}
```

This code returns with an error `Error: variable f cannot be read at compile time`.

Functional approach doesn't seem to work either:

```
enum files = ["a.txt", "b.txt"];
enum result = reduce!((a, b) => a ~ import(b))("", files);
```

It returns with the same error: `Error: variable b cannot be read at compile time`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have found a solution that doesn't use string mixins:

```
string getit(string[] a)() if (a.length > 0) {
    return import(a[0]) ~ getit!(a[1..$]);
}

string getit(string[] a)() if (a.length == 0) {
    return "";
}

enum files = ["a.txt", "b.txt"];
enum result = getit!files;
```

Comment: Easy and clean... I prefer this solution to mine!

Answer (score 5):

Maybe using string mixins?

```
enum files  = ["test1", "test2", "test3"];

// There may be a better trick than passing the variable name here
string importer(string[] files, string bufferName) {
    string result = "static immutable " ~ bufferName ~ " = ";

    foreach (file ; files[0..$-1])
        result ~= "import(\"" ~ file ~ "\") ~ ";
    result ~= "import(\"" ~ files[$-1] ~ "\");";

    return result;
}

pragma(msg, importer(files, "result"));
// static immutable result = import("test1") ~ import("test2") ~ import("test3");

mixin(importer(files, "result"));
pragma(msg, result)
```

Answer (score 3):

@Tamas answer.

It could technically be wrapped into one function using `static if` which in my opinion looks cleaner.

```
string getit(string[] a)() {
    static if (a.length > 0) {
        return import(a[0]) ~ getit!(a[1..$]);
    }
    else {
        return "";
    }
}
```

Also technically

```
static if (a.length > 0)
```

could be

```
static if (a.length)
```

You could also account for uninitialized arrays like this

```
string getit(string[] a)() {
    static if (a && a.length) {
        return import(a[0]) ~ getit!(a[1..$]);
    }
    else {
        return "";
    }
}
```

Usage would still be the same.

```
enum files = ["a.txt", "b.txt"];
enum result = getit!files;
```